# New user needs to have home folder on new drive

Tags: linux, terminal

Doing an assignment for college, I had to create a new drive that I have already partitioned, the new users home directory has to be located on this new drive, I am unsure how I can do this, I have checked my notes and can't seem to find it anywhere.

The reason for this is I need to assign a disk quota for this new user, so all their files need to be on this disk to put a quota on it.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction it would be a huge help, thank you.

Comment: You don't have anything about symlinks in your notes?

Answer (score 1):

The `adduser` and `useradd` commands have flags to select the user's home directory. For instance, if you mount the new partition in '/mnt/disk' you can place the home of a new user in the partition with the following call:

```
adduser --home /mnt/disk/<username> <username>
```